# Eclipse C/C++ Compiler Visual Studio C++

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I have just installed cdt plugin for eclipse and tried to make a new project. On the tool chain its showing Microsoft Visual C++ not MinGW. 
On writing #include  its showing Unresolved inclusion:

What should I do now? How can I have MinGW now? Please help me out.